# What is the best way for playing audio files stored on server machine?

Tags: html, audio

I uploaded a lot of audio records to my server. Every record has duration about 45 min. I would like to play this files on my website like youtube, but only in audio format. I'm using Web audio API and I heard about html5 local storage. Is it better to use this html local storage, or to play files directly from server storage? 
How to play file from absolute path on server where is stored my website? Can that be done using xmlHttpRequest or what?

Answer (score 0):

This fully functioning nodejs server might give you some traction ... save following code on your server as file media_server.js

```
// usage 
// node this_file.js


var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util');

// var path = "/path/to/audio/or/video/file/local/to/server/cool.mp4"; // put any audio or video file here
var path = "/home/stens/Dropbox/Documents/data/audio/Justice_Genesis_first_10_seconds_june.flac"; 

var port = 8888;
var host = "localhost";  //  update if using a real server not your laptop

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  var stat = fs.statSync(path);
  var total = stat.size;

  if (req.headers.range) { // meaning client (browser) has moved the forward/back slider
                           // which has sent this request back to this server logic ... cool
    var range = req.headers.range;
    var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    var partialstart = parts[0];
    var partialend = parts[1];

    var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
    var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total-1;
    var chunksize = (end-start)+1;
    console.log('RANGE: ' + start + ' - ' + end + ' = ' + chunksize);

    var file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: start, end: end});
    res.writeHead(206, { 'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total, 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': chunksize, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    file.pipe(res);

  } else {

    console.log('ALL: ' + total);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': total, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' }); // muck with making this dynamically match source media type
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
  }
}).listen(port, host);

console.log("Server running at http://" + host + ":" + port + "/");
```

then execute it by issuing a nodejs call on your server side (your laptop works just fine here too ;-)

```
node media_server.js
```

which will spin up a server listening to the chosen port 8888 ... now just point your browser at that host and port as per URL

http://localhost:8888/

and it will stream (not download) the media onto your browser and render the audio or video ... enjoy

Comment: It is okay, but I have whole layout written and my custom audio player, but main problem is that client need to wait for file to be downloaded onto browser so response time is bad. Can I keep my layout and my audio player, but to start audio immediately. You can see here http://naucikako.com/audio/RTI/3/SS/V/2013-2014/3-dvocas/1?id=557